# Is it possible to have to multiple models with same name in the same loopback app?

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I want to have 2 models with same name (Account in this case) in the same LoopBack app but mounted at different points:

For example: `http://localhost:3000/api1/Accounts` and 
`http://localhost:3000/api2/Accounts` ? Is it possible to do this?

I tried requiring two LoopBack objects, mounting them at different paths in the app and creating the models in them; but when I register the model with the app, the last call to **app.model** is the one which takes effect. Is there a way to work around this ?

```
var loopback = require('loopback');
var loopback2 = require('loopback');
var app = loopback();
app.use('/api1', loopback.rest());
app.use('/api2', loopback2.rest());
app.listen(3000);

app.dataSource('testMySql', dsConfig);
var config = { dataSource: 'testMySql'};  

var newmodel = loopback.createModel(model);  
app.model(newmodel, config);

newmodel2 = loopback2.createModel(model);  
app.model(newmodel2, config);
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure it would work the way you have it, but are you just trying to [version your API](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Versioning+your+API)? If not, maybe it would just be best to use a more distinct name? Another option would be to really have two different applications (different `server.js` files) and simply reuse some of the modules between them.

Comment: Hi, Thanks very much for the response. I'm not trying to version the API here. I'm trying to handle the case where I could have the same table name (eg. Account) in different databases or even under different schemas in the same database.

Comment: Well, I don't think you can have two models with the exact same name in the LoopBack app, so you might have to "namespace" them like: `Table1Account` and `Table2Account`. Not exactly sure the best way to do that though.